# Jsoup Getting li with multiple classes

Tags: java, class, select, html-lists, jsoup

Hello I am having some trouble obtaining an `li` item when it has multiple classes. I have verified with the jsoup css validator that my syntax is correct when I write li.class or li.class.class2.

HTML

```
<ul class="user-info">

<li class="class-one classtwo">stuff</li>`
```

I would like to get the test from the `li` above.

Stuff I have tried:

```
doc.getElementsByClass(".class-one");
doc.getElementsByClass("li.class-one");
doc.getElementsByClass("li.class-one.classtwo");

doc.select("ul") <--- returns too many elements and I cant nest the selector with `.select(".user-info")`
```

Comment: I misunderstood your question (jsoup) and my answer wasn't helping so I deleted it.  And you said doc.getElementsByClass("class-one"); returns no elements (note there is no period with the class name).

Comment: Yeah doc.getElementsByClass("class-one") should work but it returns null element list in jsoup. Elements usrLoc = doc.getElementsByClass("user-location");

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem with your `selectors` but, the problem is with the `method` selection.

You get the desired results with the following approach.

```
doc.select(".class-one"); // All Elements with atleast "class-one" class
doc.select("li.class-one"); // All <li> with atleast "class-one" class
doc.select("li.class-one.classtwo"); //  All <li> with atleast "class-one", "classtwo" classes
```

Comment: There problem was actually that the html was different when viewed in browser vs jsoup.connect(url).get()... I resolved this

Comment: @user2524908  You could have updated your `Question` or added an `Answer`  then.